# Terraform source Gitlab module

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I need help with sourcing terraform modules from a gitlab repository with multiple modules in it like ec2, vpc etc. I have two branches in module repo - develop and main. I tried all the ways below but got an error. I am sourcing something like below. I need ssh only, not https.

```
source = "git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git//ec2?ref=develop"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git//ec2?ref=develop"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git/ec2?ref=develop"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules/ec2?ref=develop"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules//ec2?ref=develop"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com/repo_name/modules//ec2?ref=develop"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git//ec2"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git?ref=ec2"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git?ref=develop//ec2"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git/develop/ec2"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git//ec2?ref=develop"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules.git/develop/ec2"
"git::ssh://git@gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules/ec2?ref=develop"
"git::ssh://git@code.gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules//ec2"
```

This is the error I am getting

```
│ 
│ Module "ec2" (declared at compute/main.tf line 1)
│ has invalid source address
│ "git::ssh://git@code.gitlabrepo.com:repo_name/modules//ec2": Terraform
│ cannot detect a supported external module source type for
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example from one of my projects:

```
module "sql_cluster" {
  source = "git::ssh://git@gitlab.com/foo/bar/tf-modules.git//data/database-cluster?ref=main"
```

Here, the branch name is "main", but note that it could be a tag or other reference.